# What is for contrib_regression DB in Postgres DBs list?

Tags: database, postgresql

I ran 2 commands

```
psql -U postgres
```

and

```
postgres=# \l
```

and then I saw

```
     List of databases
        Name        | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
--------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 contrib_regression | spuser | UTF8     | C           | C           |
```

I'm interested in purpose of `contrib_regression` DB.
All that I could google a mention of it https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/contrib-dblink-get-result.html

However, there is no explanation of `contrib_regression`.

Answer (score 2):

This database is created when you run the regression tests for a PostgreSQL extension that is built using PGXS, the [PostgreSQL extension building infrastructure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-pgxs.html).

The typical procedure is like this:

```sh
tar -xzvf extension.tgz
cd extension
make
sudo make install
make installcheck
```

The last step runs the regression tests and will create the database `contrib_regression` for that purpose.

You can safely drop that database once the regression tests are done.